# Ionic build android error ubuntu

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, npm, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic framework. I think everything was installed correctly. 
I started a example project and error occurred when I `ionic build android`. Please help and thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you setup your android environment?

Comment: @DavidePastore yes, i did